# WSDL Apache CXF Issue

Tags: soap, wsdl, cxf

So I am using a legacy WSDL,and I want to generate some Java code from it to get a better idea of what exactly the web service does as I find Java code to be easier to read than a WSDL. However, using the Apache CFX source generator plug in using the below WSDL file is giving me the following error (same one in soapUI):

Encountered illegal extension attribute "soapAction". Extension attributes must be in a namespace other than WSDL's.

So basically, I want to change the WSDL so that it still properly describes the web service, but can actually be utilized by the plug in. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. I included the whole WSDL because I did not know what parts could be relevant, so apologies for the huge wall of text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI" 
targetNamespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"
xmlns:impl="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"
xmlns:intf="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<!-- Types -->

  <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI">


      <!-- Say -->

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexTextInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="SynthString" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Encoding" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexVoiceInfo">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Owner" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexAudioInfo">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="DeliveryType" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Format" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="SignalRate" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexAudioData">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="DeliveryType" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Format" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Data" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>


      <!-- CreateAccount -->

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexCreateUserInfo">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Password" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="DOB" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Email" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="ZipCode" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Gender" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>


      <!-- Voice Search -->

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexQuery">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Owner" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Age" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Gender" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Language" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexQueryResult">
        <xsd:all>
          <xsd:element name="Owner" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Age" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Gender" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Language" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="Dialect" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:all>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="ComplexQueryResultArray">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Voice" nillable="true" type="tns:ComplexQueryResult"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>


  <!-- Messages -->

  <wsdl:message name="GetSessionIDSoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="ApplicationID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetSessionIDSoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="SessionID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="SaySoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="SessionID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="Text" type="tns:ComplexTextInfo" />
    <wsdl:part name="VoiceInfo" type="tns:ComplexVoiceInfo" />
    <wsdl:part name="AudioInfo" type="tns:ComplexAudioInfo" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="SaySoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="Audio" type="tns:ComplexAudioData" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="CreateAccountSoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="ApplicationID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="UserInfo" type="tns:ComplexCreateUserInfo" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="CreateAccountSoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="VoiceSearchSoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="SessionID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="Query" type="tns:ComplexQuery" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="VoiceSearchSoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="VoiceList" type="tns:ComplexQueryResultArray" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAccountInfoSoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="ApplicationID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="GetAccountInfoSoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="SynthesesRemaining" type="xsd:int" />
    <wsdl:part name="DefaultVoiceInfo" type="tns:ComplexVoiceInfo" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="UpdateAccountInfoSoapIN">
    <wsdl:part name="ApplicationID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="UserID" type="xsd:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="DefaultVoiceInfo" type="tns:ComplexVoiceInfo" />
    <wsdl:part name="ModifySynthesisAmount" type="xsd:int" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="UpdateAccountInfoSoapOUT">
    <wsdl:part name="SynthesesRemaining" type="xsd:int" />
    <wsdl:part name="DefaultVoiceInfo" type="tns:ComplexVoiceInfo" />
    <wsdl:part name="Error" type="xsd:string" />
  </wsdl:message>


  <!-- Port Types -->

  <wsdl:portType name="VF-HTTPS-Binding">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSessionID">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetSessionIDSoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetSessionIDSoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateAccount">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CreateAccountSoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CreateAccountSoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAccountInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetAccountInfoSoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetAccountInfoSoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateAccountInfo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateAccountInfoSoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateAccountInfoSoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:portType name="VF-HTTP-Binding">
    <wsdl:operation name="VoiceSearch">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:VoiceSearchSoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:VoiceSearchSoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Say">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:SaySoapIN" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:SaySoapOUT" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>


  <!-- Bindings -->

  <wsdl:binding name="VF-HTTPS-Binding" type="tns:VF-HTTPS-Binding">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSessionID" soapAction="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#GetSessionID">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#GetSessionID" RequestNamespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI" ResponseNamespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CreateAccount">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#CreateAccount" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAccountInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#GetAccountInfo" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateAccountInfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#UpdateAccountInfo" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="https://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:binding name="VF-HTTP-Binding" type="tns:VF-HTTP-Binding">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
    <wsdl:operation name="VoiceSearch">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#VoiceSearch" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Say">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#Say" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" style="rpc" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>


  <!-- Services -->

  <wsdl:service name="VoiceForgeAPI-S">
    <wsdl:port name="VF-HTTPS" binding="tns:VF-HTTPS-Binding">
      <wsdl:documentation>VoiceForge HTTPS Service</wsdl:documentation>
      <soap:address location="https://api.voiceforge.com/soapi.pl" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

  <wsdl:service name="VoiceForgeAPI-I">
    <wsdl:port name="VF-HTTP" binding="tns:VF-HTTP-Binding">
      <wsdl:documentation>VoiceForge HTTP Service</wsdl:documentation>
      <soap:address location="http://api.voiceforge.com/soapi.pl" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Edit with C# code generator:

//---------------------------------------------------------------
wsdl2 -out:VoiceForgeAPI.cs wsdl/soapi.wsdl
Web Services Description Language Utility
Mono Framework v2.0.50727.1433

There where some warnings while generating the code:

```
wsdl/soapi.wsdl
   - This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1
       R2209: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION SHOULD bind every wsdl:part of a
       wsdl:message in the wsdl:portType to which it refers to one of
       soapbind:body, soapbind:header, soapbind:fault  or soapbind:headerfault
         * Binding 'VF-HTTPS-Binding', in Service Description
           'http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI'
         * Binding 'VF-HTTP-Binding', in Service Description
           'http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI'
   - WARNING: At least one operation is of an unsupported type and has been
     ignored

Writing file 'VoiceForgeAPI.cs'
//---------------------------------------------------------------

And resulting file, instead of methods having just commented errors like this:
//---------------------------------------------------------------
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding GetSessionID. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding CreateAccount. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding GetAccountInfo. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding UpdateAccountInfo. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding VoiceSearch. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
// WARNING: Could not generate operation binding Say. The combination of style=rpc with use=literal is not supported
//---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see this WSDL has been created in the very dark ages of WebServices programming...

Anyway, to be able to execute:

```
wsdl2java.bat -all your.wsdl
```

you need to remove `soapAction="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#GetSessionID"` in line 207. Change:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetSessionID" soapAction="http://api.voiceforge.com/SOAPI#GetSessionID">
```

to

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetSessionID">
```

because specification of `soapAction` has to be placed in `soap:operation` extension (WSDL's Soap 1.1 Binding) element.

Issuing `wsdl2java -all` command gives me these files:

```
ComplexAudioData.java
ComplexAudioInfo.java
ComplexCreateUserInfo.java
ComplexQuery.java
ComplexQueryResult.java
ComplexQueryResultArray.java
ComplexTextInfo.java
ComplexVoiceInfo.java
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
VFHTTPBinding.java
VFHTTPBindingImpl.java
VFHTTPBinding_VFHTTP_Client.java
VFHTTPBinding_VFHTTP_Server.java
VFHTTPSBinding.java
VFHTTPSBindingImpl.java
VFHTTPSBinding_VFHTTPS_Client.java
VFHTTPSBinding_VFHTTPS_Server.java
VoiceForgeAPII.java
VoiceForgeAPIS.java
```

in `com.voiceforge.api.soapi` package.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this when I had lost all hope. I ended up just rewriting it, but hopefully this will help somebody else in the future.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry to come back here so much later and ask for some more advice, but there are very few people who seem to know a lot about WSDL files. I am trying to generate some code from the wsdl, and I am getting the errors now contained in the question.

Comment: sorry, I'm on my 2 weeks holiday. But it seems Mono (you're using it, aren't you?) does not support RPC/Literal style. try Visual Studio and WCF (I think it's wsimport.exe) or wsdl.exe. I'll look into it on 23rd july :)

Comment: No need, that makes perfect sense to me.  I just wanted the reassurance from somebody who clearly knows what they are doing when it comes to WSDLs.